# In Azure, can I report a cost of requests with certain parameter?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-application-insights

I have a function app that takes a number of arguments. Is there is a way (via App Insights or otherwise), to see a monthly cost of requests, where one of those arguments has a certain value. Better yet- to see all the costs grouped by the values of this argument.

I've looked around the App Insights, but haven't found an appropriate option so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version is that you cannot get accurate per function costs from Application Insights. The big issue with this is that you cannot see the memory usage on a per-function basis. This is a feature request for this and you can track it on [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1451). The best you will get is a comparative idea of which functions are using the most resources.

The [consumption plan billing FAQ](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Consumption-Plan-Cost-Billing-FAQ) has a lot of info on this. In particular, Azure monitor does give you a breakdown on how your function app as a whole is consuming resources.

In order to get an idea of which arguments were used, you can add a [custom metric](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics) to your functions and send it off the App Insights. You will then be able to filter and group by those parameters.

You can get good numbers for the duration and invocation counts. As long as memory usage stays constant or tracks with duration in some manner, this should give you an idea of what is costing you more money. Also keep in mind the execution count could be lower than actual because of sampling. You can change the sampling rate in the portal on the AI instance.

```
requests
| summarize count(), sum(duration) by name
```